# Laravel middleware - empty request

Tags: php, laravel, request, middleware, jwt

I'm using laravel 5.5, and tymon/jwt-auth as my jwt service provider.
When I'm using the JWTAuth facade from the controllers - all goes fine - I get the token and can manipulate any thing.

When I'm trying to use the JWTAuth facade inside a custom middleware I created - the headers are gone and the request is empty.
Quite sure it isn't a problem in laravel's middleware since JWT's middleware can get the token by the headers.

I'm running an nginx reverse proxy on port 80 which redirects to apache server on port 8080 and apache runs the laravel project.

Suggestion anyone?

Code:

api.php

```
Route::get('organizations', 'OrganizationController@index')->middleware('org');
```

Kernel.php

```
'org' => \App\Http\Middleware\OrganizationMiddleware::class,
```

OrganizationMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use JWTAuth;

class OrganizationMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
         $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
         return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);

//       return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Non of my tries goes good. The middleware answers, but the request is totally empty. So I can't get the headers or the token, or any other parameter.
Really weird. Tested locally also, only on apache, and with the appropriate .htaccess file. Also enabled CORS just in case.
Token is totally empty.

UPDATE:

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
    "illuminate/contracts": "^5.5",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "spatie/laravel-fractal": "^5.2",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.11"
},
```

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Added to the post. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try it without middleware?

Comment: Yes, without middleware it works fine.

Comment: what actual input data are you sending with this GET request? ... what query string vars?

Comment: No query strings - only Authorization header with a Bearer token.

Comment: headers aren't part of inputs ... `$request->all()` doesnt include headers or server vars as they aren't inputs ... query string or request body

Comment: So, when I use JWTAuth::getToken() or parseToken() it retrieves an empty t oken. Though it shouldn't be, since an Authorization header is attached.

Comment: because the headers are still part of the request, they are just not INPUTs which is what `$request->input()` and `$request->all()` return

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to get the token here? l've edited the code above, and still it gets an empty token.

Answer (score 0):

`$request->bearerToken()` would pull the Authorization Bearer token from the request headers.

`$request->header()` if you want to get all the headers.

`$request->header('name', 'default')` to get a header by name.

`$request->headers` to get the `HeaderBag`.

Not sure why things would be empty at this point. Version information might help.

Comment: added composer.json require tab.

Answer (score 0):

Set your jwt token into header

```
$request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer' . $token);
```

Maybe the headers get lost during redirection of request from nginx to apache. Check your server config.

Comment: Thought about it. That's why I wrote that when using controllers and jwt middlewares - all goes fine - the token is there.

Comment: @UriahAhrak may i know how did you fixed it?